# How do I sync an iCal calendar across Lion, Lepoard, and iOS 5?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar

My Dad wants to be able to sync his iCal calendar across a Lion MBP, a Leopard MB, and an iPad running iOS 5. Since the Leopard MB doesn't support iCloud, I can't use that. How can I sync an iCal calendar across all these devices?

I've tried to use Google Calendar, but with no success. Maybe it's the way I'm importing it, but I can't get the colors to show up correctly in iCal. When I link iCal to Google Calendar, I want the calendars to look the same in the sidebar. It is a bit confusing with out a screenshot, but I will post a screenshot as soon as I have my Dad's laptop.

Comment: If you want to change colors in Google Calendar across all devices, you should change it in the web interface.

Comment: @gentmatt I know you can do that. It just doesn't make sense without a screenshot. I apologize. I don't have my Dad's MB, so I can't post it. Will post it later.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use Google Calendar ([CalDav](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358#ical)). You can import these into iCal (both on iPad and Mac). It sync automatically too, so you can have all iCloud-benefits.

I use it with my girlfriend (who is, sadly enough a windows user) and with my company PC. It works like a charm!

Comment: +1 Google is the way to go! Sync across multiple devices and multiple platforms. How cool is that?!!

Comment: I've had some problems with GC. I will update my answer.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to do so, please let me know and I'll walk you through.

Comment: Did my solution work out?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a suitable work around that I have been using for a couple of months

While using iCal on a Mac running Snow Leopard, I needed to add an account to iCal. This account would point to iCloud and sync with it.

So, open Preferences and select accounts, enter the add account window by hitting +.

this takes you to:

[image]

You need to choose CalDav and enter your Apple ID email address (not your .me.com email address created when you signed up for iCloud)

enter in your password and the server name which in most cases is p06-caldav.icloud.com

Once this has been added you will need to uncheck some of the calendars in the 'on my mac' menu.

Comment: Just for clarification, would the Apple ID you're referring to be called your iCloud Apple ID or the Apple ID connected to your iCloud account—which may or may not be a "me.com" address.

Comment: yes, this is the email address you signed up to iCloud with.

Comment: Which *could* well be a me.com or mac.com address—mine is. I suggest an edit for clarity.

Comment: I have edited, but not sure why this would matter unless you had 2 accounts, as you can't have a me.com account unless you have signed up to iCloud - which requires an email address at signup.

Comment: Your original statement said *You need to choose CalDav and enter your Apple ID email address (not your .me.com email address created when you signed up for iCloud)*. In my case, and that of others, that Apple ID **is** a me.com address. Hence potential confusion. Rgds!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can make an iCloud account with either the MBP/Lion or the iPad/ios5.  Do that, if you haven't. Then read [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111014102515403&query=iCloud) that describes connecting to your iCloud calendar to Snow Leopard using CalDAV.

The gist of it is that you run a quick experiment that helps you determine which iCloud server your calendar is on, and then create a link to that account from your iCal.  I don't have a Leopard here to test with, but it does work in Snow Leopard, which, as of Feb 2012, also doesn't support iCloud, so it seems worth a try.

Edit: It seems I failed to link to the article; that link is present now. And BTW, our all Snow-Leopard household shares three calendars this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this service:

http://www.mac-daddy.co.uk/cloud-solutions/macdaddy-pro-hosting.html

It works over-the-air and is fully compatible with iOS, Mac OS X 10.5, 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8.